# class array not working

Tags: c++, arrays, class, declaration

its part of code:

```
class WierszTrojkatPascala {                    //tab,tablica is an array
private:
int tablica[];
public: 
    WierszTrojkatPascala(int n) {       
        int* tab = new int[n+1];    
        for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
            tab[i] = 0;                 

        tab[0] = 1;    

        //creating pascal triangle for n//

        for( int i=0; i<=n; i++)
            for(   int j=i; j>0; j--)
                tab[j]=tab[j]+tab[j-1];          

        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            cout<<tab[i]<<' ';

        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            tablica[i]=tab[i];   

    }   

    int wspolczynnik(int m) {         
            return tablica[m];
    }
};
```

This class creates  n'th verse of pascal triangle. In the rest part of code i want to use wpspolczynnik function. Unfortunatelty tablica[m] doesnt work. For instance when i create an object of class WierszTrojkataPascala `verse`and do `verse.wspolczynnik(1)` i am getting return equal to 2 but it should be 4. Why my verse is made correct by constructor but when i am trying to get to it by function wspolczynik() it doesnt work.
Ty in advance!

Comment: Object class members must have complete type.

Comment: Canned "I'm having trouble with arrays in C++" response: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: ty u!!!! vector worked!

Answer (score 2):

This definition of data member tablica

```
int tablica[];
```

is invalid. You have to specify the size of the array using a const expression.

Comment: So how to use tab in function wspolczynnik()?

Comment: @user3402584 I have not understood the question.